# Subtle mistake in a book about class/set distinction?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I'm reading Jech's Set Theory text and one exercise is to show that the Separation Axioms follow from the Replacement Schema.  He hints to use $F=\{(x,x):\varphi(x,p)\}$.  To show that this is a function, which is a certain sort of class, we need to know that it is a relation such that $(x,y)\in F$ and $(x,z)\in F$ together imply $y=z$.  But a relation is defined as a set of $n$-tuples.  But this commits us to the idea that the function is a set, not a class.  How do we know that $F=\{(x,x):\varphi(x,p)\}$ is a set when we haven't quantified over any set, which besides would just be a use of Separation anyway?

In general I find this class versus set distinction foggy.

Comment: Are you sure Jech uses the word "class" the same way as you are?

Comment: @GFauxPas I'm neither sure of how Jech uses the word class, I've struggled with that a lot, nor am I sure how I use the word class.

Comment: For replacement you just need to know that $F$ is functional, meaning that $\langle x,y\rangle\in F\land\langle x,z\rangle\in F\to y=z$, and this is clear.

Comment: Some treatments of set theory don't use classes at all. (I personally have not been impressed by "class theory" cf to "regular" set theory). So I would look in the index of the book to see what Jech is doing.

Comment: What I seem to be hearing in this is that yeah, this is some kind of mistake in the book.

Comment: @Addem: That is emphatically *not* what I am saying. In fact Jech say at the foot of p. $11$ and top of p. $12$ (Third Millennium edition) that ‘A class $F$ is a function if it is a relation such that $(x,y)\in F$ and $(x,z)\in F$ implies $x=y$’. A little earlier he says that a class $R$ is an $n$-ary relation if all of its elements are $n$-tuples. There is no problem here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott In my text he explicitly uses the word "set", perhaps that's all that needs to change here.

Comment: @Addem: In the edition that I have he defines both what it means for a set to be a function (relation, resp.) and what it means for a class to be a function (relation, resp.); is that not the case your edition? (What is your edition?)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  He does explicitly define theses, but I copy-paste from it: "An n-ary relation R is a set of n-tuples."

Comment: @Addem: and at the top of the next page (in my edition): ‘In general, we call a class $R$ an $n$-ary relation if all its elements are $n$-tuples; in other words, if $$R\subset V^n=\text{the class of all }n\text{-tuples}\;,$$ where $C^n$ (and $C\times D$) is defined in the obvious way.’

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah, mine has that too, but didn't see it until you pointed it out.  But mine also has the quote I pasted above.  I guess this means it has two definitions of the same word, one for the context of classes and another for the context of sets.

Comment: @Addem: Yes, exactly. The way Jech handles classes, he has to give separate definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "relation" in this context just means "*class* of ordered pairs".  So you don't have to prove $F$ is a set to use Replacement.  Indeed, this is the entire point of Replacement: it lets you construct sets from functions on set domains, even if you only know those functions are classes (rather than sets).

(More precisely, a "class" is really just a formula $\varphi(x)$ with one free variable in the language of set theory, possibly with parameters.  The axiom of replacement is usually stated in terms of formulas $\varphi(x,y)$ in *two* free variables, such that the relation it defines is a function.  That is, for any $x$, there is at most one $y$ such that $\varphi(x,y)$.  So to use Replacement directly, you don't literally consider the class consisting of ordered pairs $(x,y)$, but rather just directly talk about the formula $\varphi(x,y)$ you would use to define this class.)

Comment: Ok, I was just tripped up on the fact that Jech uses the word "set", and the fact that I have been persistently confused about the distinction between sets and classes.  But if the intended word is really "class" then I think I get it.